# how to create a combo box in access which can be converted to text box to enable writing if the user needs to add a new option to the existings?

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I was wondering how I can define a combo box in a form where the user can select an option from the existing list, and if he can't find the desired option, a "add a new option" can be accessed which converts the combo box to a text box for writing the new option?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a button next to the combo, for an 'add option' which is triggered when the combo 'not in list' event is hit - and the button then would call a popup form - or in your suggestion, changes the visibility of an overlayed text box that allows for entry.  I suggest a popup form, however, because then you can validate the input for length, content, etc - and then once the form or text box is filled in - exiting the text box, or submitting the form would save to your table for the drop down, refresh the combo box source query, and assign the value.  I do this in VBA alot with popups.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad english :-(

You can directly use the "On Not in List" event. Look at the examples at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.ComboBox.NotInList

This is the scenario: A combobox called cb and a textbox called tb. Visible property of tb is false. Combobox and Textbox have the same data source. When you type a value that is not in the combobox list, that value goes to the textbox; when you finished editing textbox, it is hidden again.

```
Private Sub cb_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer) 
    ' Suppress error message and undo changes. 
    Response = acDataErrContinue 
    Me!cb.Undo 
    ' Prompt user to verify they wish to add new value. 
    If MsgBox("Value is not in list. Add it?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then 
        Me!tb.Visible = True
        Me!tb.Value = NewData 
        Me!tb.SetFocus 
    End If 
End Sub

Private Sub tb_AfterUpdate()
    ' Hide again texbox
    Me!tb.Visible = False
    ' Update combobox items
    Me!cb.Requery
End Sub
```